# Caffe installation: common.h: No such file or directory Error:1

Tags: caffe

While doing make all for caffe configuration, compilation terminates and gives commom.h: No such file or directory and also Error:1

I have tried to install libprotobuf-dev but it gives error no matching version.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOP9H.png)

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not as an image. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)

Comment: CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:9:42: fatal error: google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
                                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1